# how to use kura and kaa together in a project?

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, iot, kura

Can I write a **kura** program that uses in **kaa**?

I want to use **kura** and **kaa** together in a project.

can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to use Kaa in a Kura bundle and it did work. 
Just import the SDK jar into your kura project, and

In active(), you initialize Kaa and call

```
kaaClient.start();
```

In deactivate(),

```
kaaClient.stop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no one has attempted to use Kaa+Kura that I know of. You would have to supply more information on what it is you are trying to do. Also, it may be worth while asking the Kaa community if Kaa works well in a Java/OSGi environment.

Thanks,

--Dave